# Best blog with comments for Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco

Please can anyone recommend some good blog for *umbraco 7* that support comments.
So far i have used combination of *Ublogzy* and *Ucomment*, but *umbraco 7* doesn't support last version of ucomment anymore. So i need some other blog with integrated comments or best solution for uBlogzy comments. Please just share link i ll do the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't say I'e tried SmartBlog in Umbraco 7 yet, but you could give that a go. http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/smart-blog

Comment: thx that blog is on MVC, but not working :( thx anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much blog packages currently available for Umbraco 7.Leaving ubogsy and blog4umbraco, only option left for you is [SmartBlog](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/smart-blog).

Else case you can try [AutoFolders](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/autofolders) which is not a blog package, but will help you till an extend to achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [Articulate](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits/articulate) which supports comments using Disqus, Google+ or facebook comments.